# Prove that $A$ is invertible when $a_0 \not=0 $ and $A^{-1}=q(A)$ for some polynomial $q$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $p(\lambda)= (-\lambda)^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1} + ... + a_0$ be characteristic polynomial of matrix $A$. Prove that $A$ is invertible when $a_0 \not=0 $ and $A^{-1}=q(A)$ for some polynomial $q$.

I proved the first part ($A$ is invertible $\Leftarrow \Rightarrow a_0 \not=0 $ ).

For the second part I was thinking of using Cayley–Hamilton theorem $q_A(A)=0$ and $$A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}A^{\sim} $$

Combining the two : $$A^{-1}=((-A)^n+A^{n-1}tr(A)+...)^{-1}A^{\sim}$$

However I'm not familiar with matrix polynomial and I'm not sure if there can be $A^{\sim}$ in one.
Is there any other way to prove it?

PS$$$$
I used $A^{\sim}$ notation for  conjugate of cofactor matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have al ready proved the first part- let me give you a hint about finding the inverse. You are right about using the Cayley Hamilton theorem too.

Let's say that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$.

Then, by Cayley Hamilton, $a_0I+a_1A+\cdots a_nA^n=0$, which means, $a_1A+\cdots+a_nA^n=-a_0I$.

Thus,

$A(a_1I+a_2A+\cdots+a_nA^{n-1})=-a_0I$. Now divide the LHS by $-a_0$ (which is non zero by assumption), to get the inverse.

Comment: @ŽanŽurič: Yes: For your relation (1), we have $A^~=(det A)A^{-1}$ and $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A$.

Comment: Ok, thank you I got it. I have one more question though. Can conjugate of cofactor matrix be in a matrix polynomial?

Comment: @ŽanŽurič: Yes :). Somehow my comment got posted before you asked the question in the comments :-P

Comment: @voldermort Haha. So would my proof hold in that case?

Comment: @ŽanŽurič: I am not entirely convinced that you had the right formula for $A^{-1}$- but other than that you had all the right ideas. Check your formula for 2x2 matrices, say to see if it's correct or not.

Comment: @voldermort
The formula is used in Cramer's rule I think. The matrix A~ is called Adjugate matrix as I looked up the english word for it. The formula is correct for 2x2 matrices.

Comment: @ŽanŽurič: O - in that case you are fine :). Yes as I remember Cramer's rule also gives the inverse as a polynomial in entries of $A$. However, I like the Cayley- Hamilton Theorem better. (Just a personal preference).